# ArduinoBT UART Communications

Tags: arduino, power, bluetooth, sleep

Is there any way to monitor what is being sent to the WT-11 module via UART?

I'm trying to implement deep sleep on the WT-11 and can run the iWRAP "TEST DEEPSLEEP" command successfully but the deep sleep lasts for less than a minute.  The iWRAP [datasheet](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/iWRAP_2.2.0_User_Guide.pdf) says that this command "Puts the module into deep-sleep after a delay of half a second until woken by a reset or activity on UART."

I don't think I'm doing anything that should end deep sleep.  Is there something lower level on the ArduinoBT that may be interferring?

I also can't get the "SLEEP" command to work, this may be related.

(The code I'm running is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/828/bluetooth-power-saving-mode-for-arduinobt/834#834))

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your first question, looking at the schematic for the ArduinoBT (available [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardBluetooth)), there is a connector called J1 that has the UART connections on Pins 1 & 2.  You could make a connector that links these two pins up to a monitor cable (something like one of  [these](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/cable/RS-232-spy-monitor.html) with level shifting if you're using a PC to monitor and aren't using a USB TTL UART cable).

If you use the full duplex one, you can use [Docklight](http://www.docklight.de) to monitor both ports at the same time*; with the half duplex one any serial terminal software will work.

If you want to monitor the reset line (pin 11 of J1), you'll have to use an correctly triggered oscilloscope probably.

* Note that if you use USB serial leads like the ones [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/EvaluationKits/USB-Serial.htm) manufacture, the UART communication is buffered, so you can't tell in what order the data arrives with a full duplex monitor cable.